# Porqué no se envía correctamente?

Tags: python

No sé porqué cuando envío un entero por un socket (previamente transformado en string) no se llega a enviar la información correctamente, aquí parte del código del programa servidor.

```
# ...
# El nombre del archivo le llega al servidor del cliente
print(f"Cliente quiere recibir {nom_arch}. Enviando archivo...")

tam = os.path.getsize(nom_arch)
conn.send(str(tam).encode('utf-8'))  # enviamos el tamano del archivo
```

Luego, en el programa cliente, lo recibo de esta forma.

```
# se ejecuta el bloque try
try:
    tam = cliente.recv(BUFSIZE).decode('utf-8')
    # no se recibe tam correctamente y entra en el condicional siguiente
    if not tam:
        print("Error: No se ha recibido nada del servidor.")
        cliente.close()
        return
    tam = int(tam)
except ValueError:
    print("Error: archivo no valido")
    cliente.close()
    return
```

Y como se indica en el comentario, no se recibe tam correctamente y se ejecuta el condicional `if not tam`. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El metodo recv devuelve una cadena vacía en caso de error o de que la conexión haya sido cerrada. Parece que estás cerrando la conexión antes de que el  servidor lea los datos....pero no se puede asegurar sin ver todo el código